# Convert Int number into Binary in Node Red

Tags: javascript, binary, buffer, node-red

I am taken Data from a pressure sensor using node-red for sampling purpose I want to convert into binary I don't know how to convert data help me to solve this problem

my output is msg.payload = 10200 is converted into 0010 0111 1101 1000

Comment: look at Number toString documentation

Comment: What do you mean by convert to binary? Do you mean convert the number to a string made up of 1 & 0s or do you mean send the data as a raw byte value that matches the input decimal number?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a string just containing 1&0s then the quickest way without installing any extra nodes:

Function node with the following:

```
msg.payload = msg.payload.toString(2);
return msg;
```

If you want to send a buffer (raw byte values) then you can do something similar:

```
var buffer = Buffer.alloc(2);
buffer.writeInt16BE(msg.payload,0);
msg.payload = buffer;
return msg;
```

The [node-red-contrib-binary](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-binary) node mentioned in the other answer can do the same, but is a lot more powerful and will is designed more for converting JSON objects in to compact binary data structures or back the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Follow
[this link](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-binary)
 and use the command line to install the node if not currently present then place node between the initial payload and the output.

Comment: This is a link only answer that will become useless as soon as the link breaks. Edit the answer to include the details of the answer, links should only be for reference.